# How to convert from NSNumber to .NET Object

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin.ios, nsnumber

When working with .NET iOS targets (ie. `net6.0-ios`, `net6.0-maccatalyst`, Xamarin, MAUI, etc.), there are methods on `NSNumber` for converting to a specific .NET type.  For example, `.BooleanValue`, `.Int32Value`, `.DoubleValue`, etc.

But what should one do if you don't know the type in advance, and just want a .NET `object` (boxing the actual `bool`, `int`, `double`, or whatever)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension method that I came up with.  It uses the [`ObjCType` encoded values](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html), and handles `bool` and `decimal` values properly.

It's not perfect though.  For example, `NSNumber.FromByte(255).ToObject()` gives back an `object` containing an `Int16`, so it would appear that while `"c"` comes through for `sbyte` values, that `byte` value give `"s"` rather than `"C"`.  Not sure why.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Converts an <see cref="NSNumber"/> to a .NET primitive data type and returns the result box in an <see cref="object"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n">The <see cref="NSNumber"/> to convert.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="object"/> that contains the number in its primitive type.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown when the <see cref="NSNumber.ObjCType"/> was unrecognized.</exception>
/// <remarks>
/// This method always returns a result that is compatible with its value, but does not always give the expected result.
/// Specifically:
/// <list type="bullet">
///   <item><c>byte</c> returns <c>short</c></item>
///   <item><c>ushort</c> return <c>int</c></item>
///   <item><c>uint</c> returns <c>long</c></item>
///   <item><c>ulong</c> returns <c>long</c> unless it's > <c>long.MaxValue</c></item>
///   <item>n/nu types return more primitive types (ex. <c>nfloat</c> => <c>double</c>)</item>
/// </list>
/// Type encodings are listed here:
/// https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html
/// </remarks>
public static object ToObject(this NSNumber n)
{
    if (n is NSDecimalNumber d)
    {
        // handle NSDecimalNumber type directly
        return (decimal)d.NSDecimalValue;
    }

    return n.ObjCType switch
    {
        "c" when n.Class.Name == "__NSCFBoolean" => n.BoolValue, // ObjC bool
        "c" => n.SByteValue, // signed char
        "i" => n.Int32Value, // signed int
        "s" => n.Int16Value, // signed short
        "l" => n.Int32Value, // signed long (32 bit)
        "q" => n.Int64Value, // signed long long (64 bit)
        "C" => n.ByteValue, // unsigned char
        "I" => n.UInt32Value, // unsigned int
        "S" => n.UInt16Value, // unsigned short
        "L" => n.UInt32Value, // unsigned long (32 bit)
        "Q" => n.UInt64Value, // unsigned long long (64 bit)
        "f" => n.FloatValue, // float
        "d" => n.DoubleValue, // double
        "B" => n.BoolValue, // C++ bool or C99 _Bool
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(n), n,
            $"NSNumber \"{n.StringValue}\" has an unknown ObjCType \"{n.ObjCType}\" (Class: \"{n.Class.Name}\")")
    };
}
```

Comment: If anyone can improve on this, please add your own answer and feel free to copy this as a starting point.  Thanks.